# Writing a function that changes the value in one column based on search in second column in data.table in R

Tags: r, function, data.table

So I've written a function to change the value in one column based on the value in another one as I need to do this quite often. However, I cannot get it to work. Help is much appreciated!

```
dt <- data.table(mtcars)

ittt <- function(dt, col.a, col.b, if.a, then.b){
  a<-dt[col.a == if.a, col.b := then.b]

  }

a<-ittt(dt = dt, col.a = 'mpg', col.b = 'disp', if.a = 21, then.b = 000)
a

dt[mpg == 21, disp := 999]
dt
```

Comment: Looks like `ittt <- function(dt, col.a, col.b, if.a, then.b){ expr <- substitute(x == if.a, list(x = as.name(col.a))); dt[eval(expr), (col.b) := then.b][] }` might do it.

Comment: @RichScriven Thanks that worked perfectly. Would you mind explaining the `expr` part and the `[]` at the end?

Comment: If you downvote please leave a comment on why you don't like the question.  I researched before and could not find anything that made sense to me (even now I do not understand the answer) so I felt legitimized asking. I also provided a reproducible example.

Comment: I downvoted because I do not think it is a useful question (which is a pretty common reason for downvotes). In my opinion (and yes, I am allowed to vote based on my opinion), if you are doing this sort of thing often, you should formalize it by putting the changes into a proper structure (like a data.table) and then merge the values in. Getting into metaprogramming for this simple and common task looks counterproductive.

Comment: @Frank for sure you are allowed to vote based on opinion. I merely seek to improve the way I as questions on SO.

Comment: Ok, my recommendation for an alternative approach would look something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/data.table/4976/joins-and-merges/17560/update-values-in-a-join#t=201609242322347418696

Comment: Actually I think this function didn't save you any typing. It only make a very simple operation difficult to understand. And to pass variables to data.table syntax is not the most natural thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be. Remember to validate input in your function, to make sure user is passing existing column names, and expected data types.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(mtcars)

ittt <- function(dt, col.a, col.b, if.a, then.b, in.place=FALSE){
    ii = substitute(lhs == rhs, list(lhs=as.name(col.a), rhs=if.a))
    jj = substitute(lhs := rhs, list(lhs=as.name(col.b), rhs=then.b))
    if (!in.place) dt = copy(dt)
    dt[eval(ii), eval(jj)][]
}

a<-ittt(dt = dt, col.a = 'mpg', col.b = 'disp', if.a = 21, then.b = 000)
a

# if you update in.place, then no assignment to new variable required
ittt(dt = dt, col.a = 'mpg', col.b = 'disp', if.a = 21, then.b = 000, in.place=TRUE)
```

I see it is pretty much the same as solution proposed by Rich in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `[[` to get a column by using its name as a variable. You could use `ifelse` to apply an element wise conditions on the content.

```
ittt <- function(dt, col.a, col.b, if.a, then.b){
    dt[[col.b]] <- ifelse(dt[[col.a]] == if.a, then.b, dt[[col.b]])
    dt
}
```

Comment: Sorry non of these work for me. It either still doesn't find col.b or doesn't change anything

Comment: I have rewriten my answer and tested it. This works!